# Getting Status "404 Not Found" while triggering Send via Postman

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, triggered-send, marketingcloudapi

I am trying to trigger a Trigger Send with a simple payload using Postman, however the TS is not being sent.
Note: No response body is generated, the only thing that it shows is "404 Not Found"

```
POST: {{rest_url}}messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:TS_ExternalKey/send

{    
    "To": {        
        "Address": "EmailAddress",        
        "SubscriberKey": "SF_Contact_Key",        
        "ContactAttributes": 
        {            
            "SubscriberAttributes": 
            {                
                "ResetURL" : "https://www.google.com/"
            }        
        }    
    },    
        "Options": 
    {        
    "RequestType": "SYNC"    
    }
}
```

In the Email, I am using the following AMPScript:

```
set @resetURL = ResetURL
<a href="%%=redirectto(@resetURL)=%%">Link</a>
```

What could be the possible reason for this behavior?

Comment: Does the value that you have in your `{{rest_url}}` Postman variable end with a "/"?  If not, that'll cause an invalid URL.  (E.g., if you have `www.salesforce.com` as your variable value, what you have above will come out as `www.salesforce.commessaging/...`.)

Comment: Yes, {{rest_url}} has / towards the end.

Comment: Trigger Sends are completely new to me, so forgive my ignorance.  But are `rest_url` and `resetURL` supposed to be two different things?

Comment: @Moonpie, Yes they both are different.  {{rest_url}} --> I have used my REST API Endpoint here, while in ResetURL, I am trying to pass a URL to a website.

Comment: Since no one with Trigger Send knowledge is answering just yet, I'll just keep going with the more obvious things to me. 1] Are you certain that the value in your `{{rest_url}}` variable is correct - that there is no typo in the URL? 2] Is `TS_ExternalKey` just your placeholder here so as to not give out sensitive data, or is that your actual key?  a] If it _is_ your key, are you sure that is correct? b] Or is it in a variable, so should it be `{{TS_ExternalKey}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the reasons I can think of for your 404 response

1. Incorrect External Key
2. Incorrect route, is this a legacy triggered send or a new transactional messaging triggeredsend
3. Auth token is in the context of a different BU (IE token is for EID. TS is in CHILD BU)
4. You aren't making a POST but a PUT/PATCH
5. Your TSE endpoint is incorrect for the BU that has the TS

Comment: I checked and I can confirm that I have used the right details to trigger this send, but yet I get the same Status "404" without a response body. Also this is a new transactional messaging triggeredsend

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using the new transacional API, then you shoudl be calling this route:

```
POST 
/messaging/v1/email/messages/{messageKey}
```

Here’s an example request:

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /messaging/v1/email/messages/f4fe74b7-c3c0-4e5a-9f49-b63a641109a2
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
  "definitionKey": "2FA_order_accounts",
  "recipient":
  {
   "contactKey": "recipient2",
    "to": "recipient2@example.com",
    "attributes": {
      "UserAttribute_1": "value_1",
      "UserAttribute_n": "value_n"
    }
  }
}
```

Read more here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved as soon as I added the line "account_id: MID" in the Auth Request. In my case the MID here belonged to a child Business Unit.

Not sure why this was required as the Installed App created was only suppose to interact with this Child Business Unit.

Comment: So number three from my above comment. You must of created the app in the eid even though you only gave permission to child bu